# Not calling javascript when Eval in included

Tags: asp.net, eval

```
<input type="button" onclick='<%#"setIFrameSrc("+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CCM_Name")+")"%>' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value='<%#Eval("CCM_Name") %>' />
```

This is my line of asp code where i want to call the setIFrameSrc() when button is clicked, but there is some error.the method is not being called. Please point out ot me where i'm making the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it,

```
onclick='<%#String.Format("setIFrameSrc(\"{0}\")", Eval("CCM_Name").ToString()) %>'
```

The above code i have written is also correct,but it will give error when we pass string as eval value.

Comment: So you're aware, the use of `javascript:` is not actually necessary when being use on an event attribute.  It's really only necessary when being used on `<a href="javascript:doThis();">`

Comment: although i was aware that it is not necessary when being use on an event attribute, but i had no idea that it is necessary on <a href="javascript:doThis()"/> edited my answer accordingly :)

Comment: If you don't have it on the `href`, then the link would become `http://www.mydomain.com/doThis()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the right combination of single and double quotes.

*Change*

```
onclick='<%#"setIFrameSrc("+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CCM_Name")+")"%>'
```

*To*

```
onclick='<%#setIFrameSrc(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CCM_Name"))%>'
```

Comment: Error "setIFrameSrc" does not exist in the current context

Comment: Is it server side method?, if so that make it protected/public.

Comment: Show the generated html and javascript function definition